# Probability of rolling any set of size k on n dice with m sides

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, dice, binomial-distribution

I have been trying to find a solution for this problem for some while and after quite some research I got referred here.

I am looking for a mutable way to calculate the odds of rolling any set of any size on a certain number of dice, a set being dice showing the same faces.
For example: Exactly $2$ of $7$ ten-sided dice showing the same face, where the face could be any of the sides.
Or: Exactly $4$ of $9$ ten-sided dice showing the same face.

Many of the solutions I've found so far only work for very specific scenarios (like calculating the odds for zero sets and subtracting from $1$ to get the probability of at least one set of doubles).

I feel my best try so far has been by way of combinatorics. Assuming the first example:
There are $10$ possibilities for the face of the set, ${}^7\mathrm C_2 (=21)$ possibilities to pick for the set and ${}^9\mathrm C_5 (=126)$ possibilities to pick five unique faces for the remaining five dice. Divided by the total number of $10^7$ possible combinations, that gives me $0.002646$, or $2.646\%$ to roll any doubles and five singles on seven dice, which seems a tad low.

Ideally, there would also be a way to easily expand the formula to easily calculate the probability of several sets on one roll.

Comment: There are too many ways to specify such a problem for a single "formula" to be universally applicable.  Think about:  "How many ways can you roll five seven-sided dice such that the number of dice showing odd-valued faces on the first roll is a prime (and two must have the same value) and the number of dice on the second roll showing even-valued faces (except for $4$) is odd?"  You can make arbitrarily complex such problems, requiring permutations, combinations, exclusions, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want the probability of rolling exactly $5$ of a kind in $9$ normal dice. There are $6$ ways to choose the number on the set, $\binom 95$ to choose the dice which show that number, and $5^4$ ways to choose the results of the other dice, giving a probability of $\frac{6\binom 95 5^4}{6^9}$.

(Here $\binom nr={}^n\mathrm C_r$ is the binomial coefficient.)

Unfortunately it's not that simple in general. What goes wrong if you try the same approach for $4$ of a kind? It looks like there should be $6\binom 945^5$ rolls which work, but here it's possible that the "other" $5$ dice not in the set will give you another set of $4$. If this happens you've counted the same roll twice: a set of $2$s on dice $1,3,4,7$ with the other dice showing $3,5,3,3,3$ is the same as a set of $3$s on dice $2,6,8,9$ with the rest showing $2,2,2,5,2$. So you need to subtract off combinations with two sets of $4$.

In general you need the [inclusion-exclusion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), and you have to keep going until you hit the maximum number of sets you can fit in. So a general formula for the number of ways to make a set of $k$ from $n$ dice with $r$ sides would be:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\min(r,\lfloor n/k\rfloor)}(-1)^i\frac{n!}{k!^i(n-ik)!}\binom ri(r-i)^{n-ki},$$
and then you divide by $r^k$ to get the probability.

(Here we use the convention that if $r-i=n-ki=0$ then $(r-i)^{n-ki}=1$.)

The $i$th term in the above formula corresponds to counting the number of ways with $i$ sets, not worrying about overcounting (because later terms fix the overcounting). So there are $\binom ri$ ways to choose the numbers on the $i$ sets, $\binom nk$ ways to choose which dice correspond to the lowest numbered set, $\binom{n-k}k$ for the second, and so on (the product of those terms comes out as $\frac{n!}{k!^i(n-ik)!}$), and finally $(r-i)^{n-ki}=1$ possible rolls of the leftover dice, if any.

Comment: It depends what you are trying to count, I suppose. I am giving the number of ways to have at least one group of size exactly $k$. So, for example, I would count $1,2,1,2,2$ as having a group of exactly two. This seems to me to exactly be the "probability of any set of size $k$ on $n$ dice with $m$ sides".

Comment: ah, you are right... I imagined a more complex situation that dont fit very well to the wording as yours.

Comment: It's very helpful in any case, however I'm also curious how to get the probability for a single set with the remaining dice showing unique numbers.

Comment: That is easier: to get a single set of $k>1$ with all the rest being singles then you need $n-k<r$ (else there aren't enough different values available) and the number of combinations that work is just $r\binom nk(r-1)(r-2)...(r-(n-k))$ ($r$ choices for the number on the set, $\binom nk$ for which dice form the set, and $r-1$ choices for the first non-set die down to $r-(n-k)$ for the last.

Comment: Thank you. In theory I could also calculate the odds of rolling exactly two sets of different values this way, for example, right? I'd simply calculate the odds for one set and zero other sets and then use $n-k$ as $n$ and $r-1$ as $r$ for to get the odds of obtaining exactly one set on the remaining dice. Finally I'd multiply the results and that should get me there, or am I entirely wrong?

Comment: That's not quite right, as you're multiplying for all others being different twice there. There are $\binom nk$ possible places for your first set, and the probability of them being a set is $1/r^{k-1}$. You can multiply those together, and then multiply by the probability of exactly one set from the rest (using $n-k$ and $r-1$ as you say). Finally, you need to divide by two as you've counted everything twice, since you can pick either set to be the "first" set.

Answer (score 0):

Your working is fine, except for we have $5!=120$ ways to arrange the remaining unique faces, giving $\approx31.8\%$.

Comment: I figured that $!5$ would yield all possibilities for the remaining five dice, including additional sets of doubles, triples or even four and five of a kind. Since there were 9 possibilities for the first die, 8 for the second one and so on if I want to make sure that no other combinations occur I thought to exclude those by picking five from nine.

Comment: i would say your next problem is; if $k=3$ how to eliminate repeated pairs